# Zen sub-theme block page problems

Tags: theming, blocks

I have just began re-themeing a client website with a Zen STARTERKIT.

I noticed the drag'n'drop handle for grabbing and moving blocks is not showing up.
This of course means I can't reposition blocks.

I scrapped the theme and started again with a fresh install of Zen but I got the same problem.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Deleted my answer as it won't help on the blocks page.

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that something in the sub theme is wrong. There are several steps to go through. They are detailed in  starter kit readme.

Answer (score 1):

Are you including an extra copy of jQuery?  Just had an issue where the problem was an extra jQuery inclusion.  The grippies were not showing up.  Removed the extra jQuery include file and it works as expected.

Some other things to check:

- JS aggregation (turn it off)
- Ensure that `<?php echo $scripts; ?>` is inside the `<head>` tag.
- Verify is that the module "Theme Developer" is deactivated.

Check out [this thread](http://drupal.org/node/1245510) and [this thread](http://drupal.org/node/784266) for more information.